# Git Extensions vs GitHub for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows, git-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express. I know that this edition does not support git extensions integration. So I have tried a standalone source control Gui like git extensions but today I have seen another possibility that is GitHub for Windows.

I would like to know which is the difference between Git extensions and GitHub for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As [illustrated here](https://github.com/blog/1420-github-for-windows-recent-improvements), GitHub for Windows (G4W) can interface with only the latest version of Visual Studio.

This is the main difference, in the context of your question, with [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), which is a plugin for Visual Studio (2005/2008/2010/2012), as [shown in this article](http://blog.discountasp.net/using-git-with-visual-studio-2010-an-introduction-2/).

[image: http://blog.discountasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Visual-Studio-2010-Source-Control-Git-Source-Control-Provider-Options.png]

As such, Git Extensions isn't a "stand alone GUI".

You would compare, for "stand alone" GUIs, a G4W and an [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview)  for instance.

Comment: well, i mean that git extensions has its own graphical user interface and you can do all from there and also, another possibility if you have visual studio (not express) is a plug-in that fully integrates into visual studio. Also I have installed github for windows and comparing to git extensions, github it is very simple and seems to be not complet as git extensions.

Comment: @user304602 I agree. For Visual Studio, stick with Git Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same question. Maybe this will help the next person.

**Git for Windows** - is a lightweight, native set of tools that bring the full feature set of the Git SCM(source control management software) to Windows while providing appropriate user interfaces for experienced Git users and novices alike. ([source](https://git-for-windows.github.io))
This tool can also be installed separately by visiting https://git-for-windows.github.io.  This tools is not just for github but for git in general.

**GitHub Extensions for Visual Studio** - "lets you connect to GitHhub.com or GitHub enterprise and work with GitHub repositories inside of the visual studio IDE." (source: MS help)  It adds a functionality(like context menus) inside of Visual Studio for things like creating and cloning repositories. (more [here](https://visualstudio.github.com))

Answer (score -1):

Git for windows lack lot of must have feature. gitextensions is most powerful GUI I ever use. Go for https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Comment: Could you elaborate on the differences?